# Ebean shutdown is broken on Play Test

Tags: java, playframework-2.2, ebean

We have made a structure of tests in our Play Server using a base test where we clean the in memory data base and then make the evolutions. A simple snapshot of the code is the following:

```
public static void ddlConfiguration() {
    String serverName = "default";
    server = Ebean.getServer(serverName);
    ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
    ddl = new DdlGenerator();

    // Get the database engine
    String jdbc = settings.get("db.default.url");
    String[] splittedUrl = jdbc.split(":");
    String engine = splittedUrl[1];
    if(engine.equals("h2")){
        ddl.setup((SpiEbeanServer) server, new H2Platform(), config);
    }else{
        ddl.setup((SpiEbeanServer) server, new MySqlPlatform(), config);
    }

}
@Before
public void startApp() throws IOException {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication(settings);
    Helpers.start(app);

    ddlConfiguration();
} 
@After
public void stopApp() {
    // We clean the database at the end of the test in order not to overwrite
    // the onStart App initialization
    cleanDb();
    Helpers.stop(app);
}
```

The problem is once all the tests are executed and Play server shutdows there is an exception thrown like the following:

```
[error] c.a.e.s.c.DefaultServer - Error unregistering Ebean Ebean:server=default2
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Ebean:server=default2,key=AutoFetch
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:415) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:546) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.shutdownInternal(DefaultServer.java:406) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.shutdownManaged(DefaultServer.java:379) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
[error] c.a.e.s.c.DefaultServer - Error unregistering Ebean Ebean:server=default3
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Ebean:server=default3,key=AutoFetch
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:415) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:546) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.shutdownInternal(DefaultServer.java:406) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.shutdownManaged(DefaultServer.java:379) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
```

The first line of each error is reported from "[error] c.a.e.s.c.DefaultServer - Error unregistering Ebean Ebean:server=default2"  to "[error] c.a.e.s.c.DefaultServer - Error unregistering Ebean Ebean:server=default38". So I believe this is due to EbeanSevers which are not shutdown.

So, how can I correctly close them?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there are naming conflicts.

Where you have:

```
String serverName = "default";
server = Ebean.getServer(serverName);
```

Change it to something with unique server names:

```
String serverName = "default" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
server = Ebean.getServer(serverName);
```

Of course you can use some counter or similar, just make sure the names of the Ebean Servers are unique.

Comment: It still thows the same error but it is reduced in repetitions. Thank you very much.

Comment: What version of Ebean is that? (I'm thinking that is an older version)